# iOS Mail is not text wrapping on some email replies

Tags: mail.app

Writing a new email on the iOS Mail app does the proper text wrapping once typing a sentence reaches the right edge of the text editor. Replying to an email *may* do this too, but that is *not always the case*.

It seems like desktop browser created long standing Gmail threads or perhaps threads with images  or larger HTML widths are more likely to create this issue when trying to reply through the iPhone app.

iOS Outlook seems to handles text wrapping properly:

[image: text wrapping on iOS Outlook app]

Some people think [this is not a bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/ctpwbv/text_wrapping_on_iphone_mail_is_this_fixed_in_ios/), while some are [infuriated about it](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/native-apple-mail-app-wrap-text.2187296/). I tried turning OFF, then ON the [Increase Quote Level](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7701147), without success.

*obs: this was tried on iOS 13.3.1.*

Comment: Sorry to say that this is set by the app sending the email, and some mail clients don't honor the enforced lack of word-wrap (Outlook) and some rigorously follow the rules even if they should be broken due to the small screen size (mail.app). Your choice is not so much a setting or getting a company to fix a bug but to find an email app that behaves in your preferred word-wrap way and isn't too overly annoying in any other behaviors.